# Sacar valor array php

Tags: php, mongodb

Tengo que hacer una aplicación PHP con conexión a MongoDB. Estoy tratando de conseguir una lista de usuarios y rellenar un objeto, en este caso para el login.

Consigo sacar la lista pero no sacar los valores individuales para guardarlos en mi clase Usuario.

[image]

Código PHP de la página con el formulario:

```
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $usuario = new Usuario(0, $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass'],0); //Le damos valores del formulario y el resto ahora los cargaremos
    if ($usuario->autenticar()){ //Filtro autenticacion

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $usuario->getEmail();
        $_SESSION['password'] = $usuario->getPassword();
        $_SESSION['power'] = $usuario->getPower();

        //print_r($_SESSION);
    } else {
        echo "No puedes entrar";
    }
}
```

Codigo que busca en BD:

```
public static function buscarUsuarioLogin($usuario){
        $connection= new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        $filter = ['email' => $usuario->getEmail(), 'password' => $usuario->getPassword()];
        $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
        return $connection->executeQuery("Plataforma.Usuarios", $query);
    }
```

Este es el codigo que imprime la lista. Llama a un metodo en una clase aparte que retorna todo lo que haya en la base de datos que coincida con el email y la contraseña de mi clase usuario, que la meto por POST:

```
        public function autenticar(){
        $checker = false;
        $rows = DaoUsuarios::buscarUsuarioLogin($this);
        foreach ($rows as $document){
            print_r($document);
            //echo $document["power"];
            //echo $rows["power"];
            //$this->power = $rows['power'];
            //$this->id = $rows['oid'];
           // $checker = true;
        }
        return $checker;
    }
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es lo que tengo comentado. Imprimo el documento al completo pero no soy capaz de sacar un dato en específico y manipularlo. Algo como $this->power = $document['power'] pero me da error. He probado con comillas simples y dobles, que tengo entendido que es importante en este lenguaje pero se escapa a mi entendimiento el por qué esto no funciona.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede ver que `$document` es del tipo `stdClass Object`.

Para acceder a las propiedades y métodos de un [objeto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php) se utiliza la sintaxis:

```
$obj->prop; // propiedad
$obj->method(); // metodo
```

#### Solución:

Podes acceder a las propiedades del `$document`, así:

```
echo $document->_id->oid;
echo $document->email;
echo $document->password;
echo $document->power;
```